# Closing bootstrap4 Accordian which is generated in table when another is opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap-4 for generating accordians in table. I am appending another tr when clicked on the image which results opening of accordian. And next in the accordian i am appending another tr to each tr means accordian in accordian. Now what the problem is i want to close accordian when another is opened.

I am using a bit java script to close the second accordian on clicking on the button. but it is not a problem. i want to close the accordian when another is opened.
I am providivg the link below for the code..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dJDHd/2190/   here is the link of my code\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi try this http://jsfiddle.net/dJDHd/2191/

Solution is you just have to trigger collapse hide for other. I have used a class to differentiate between the element which has collapse shown.

Just run the js fiddle, its working fine

http://jsfiddle.net/dJDHd/2191/

```
$('.hiddenRow .accordian-body').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('.hiddenRow.has-collapse-shown .accordian-body').collapse('hide');
});

$('.hiddenRow .accordian-body').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
    $(this).parent('.hiddenRow').addClass('has-collapse-shown');
});


$('.hiddenRow .accordian-body').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
    $(this).parent('.hiddenRow').removeClass('has-collapse-shown');
});
```